# SQL Procedure Error - INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Error:

> Msg 121, Level 15, State 1, Procedure InsertNonExistingNode, Line 5
>   The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the
>   insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of
>   INSERT columns.

Procedure in SQL Management Studio:

```
USE NWatchEntitiesUnitTest
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE InsertNonExistingNode (@TableVariable dbo.NodeTableTable READONLY, @ScalarParameter nvarchar(255))
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO NWatchNodes WITH (ROWLOCK) (
      NodeTypeId,
      Location,
      DisplayName,
      AccessLevel,
      IsEnabled,
      CreatedOn,
      CreatedBy,
      ModifiedOn,
      ModifiedBy,
      NativeId,
      SourceId,
      Name,
      Alias) 

    SELECT 
    NodeTypeId,
    Name,
    Location,
      DisplayName,
      AccessLevel,
      IsEnabled,
      CreatedOn,
      CreatedBy,
      ModifiedOn,
      ModifiedBy,
      NativeId,
      SourceId,
      Name,
      Alias

    FROM @TableVariable t
        /*Left Join then where ID is null to make sure the record doesn't exists*/
        LEFT JOIN NWatchNodes PR WITH (NOLOCK) 
                                ON  PR.ID = @ScalarParameter
                                AND PR.Name = t.Name
        WHERE PR.ID IS NULL
END

GO
```

Comment: what do you think this error message means? did you count the amount of columns you are selecting against the amount of columns in your insert? you might notice that `Name` is present twice in your select.

Comment: You are correct!  I'd like to change this question to the error I am getting now, if you don't mind, since that was just an overlook on my side.

Comment: @blgrnboy - you shouldn't change a question once you have *answers*, if changing the question will invalidate the answers. I'd suggest opening a new question, whilst this one should probably be closed as a typographical error.

Comment: As @Damien_The_Unbeliever is right, just to give you a quick hint, check if two columns have the same name in both tables, you need to select a specific value from one column, that´s your new error message.

Comment: Would I do so by:
SELECT 
 TableVariable.NodeTypeId,
 TableVariable.Name,
 TableVariable.Location,
...

Comment: It is ok if you overlook it, just correct your query, if have another concern or different error, dont modify the question because it already have an answer, so that the readers will not misunderstood the answers, @Damien_The_Unbeliever is correct, i suggest opening a new question if you have different concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a missing column in your `INSERT` , the column is `Name` , you have `Name` column in your `SELECT` statement, but not in `INSERT`.

To fix, just put `Name` in your insert statement between `NodeTypeId` and `Location`.

Below are the correct query to remove your error, but it seems you `select` the name twice, so its either you will remove the `name` column after `NodeTypeId` in your select statement, or you will add it in your insert, see below adding the missing column.

```
INSERT INTO NWatchNodes WITH( ROWLOCK )
       ( NodeTypeId,
         Name, -->> This column is the cause of error, because its missing
         Location,
         DisplayName,
         AccessLevel,
         IsEnabled,
         CreatedOn,
         CreatedBy,
         ModifiedOn,
         ModifiedBy,
         NativeId,
         SourceId,
         Name,
         Alias
       )
       SELECT NodeTypeId,
              Name,
              Location,
              DisplayName,
              AccessLevel,
              IsEnabled,
              CreatedOn,
              CreatedBy,
              ModifiedOn,
              ModifiedBy,
              NativeId,
              SourceId,
              Name,
              Alias
```

Comment: Yup , to fix the error he need to add `Name`, i dont know if he want to select it twice, but my concern is the error :)

Comment: @KevinEsche , i put sample code and explanation for him to understand his error :)

Comment: Not true... the names of the inserted columns do not have to match, but the columntypes do of course. The answer is in the number of columns inserted, that has to be equal to the number of columns listed in the INSERT statement...

Comment: @Tom ,yup you are correct.. but it doesn't seem that there is a problem with the answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Your select clause has 14 columns

```
      NodeTypeId,
      Name,
      Location,
      DisplayName,
      AccessLevel,
      IsEnabled,
      CreatedOn,
      CreatedBy,
      ModifiedOn,
      ModifiedBy,
      NativeId,
      SourceId,
      Name,
      Alias
```

But in your INSERT only 13

```
  NodeTypeId,
  // You are missing Name here
  Location,
  DisplayName,
  AccessLevel,
  IsEnabled,
  CreatedOn,
  CreatedBy,
  ModifiedOn,
  ModifiedBy,
  NativeId,
  SourceId,
  Name,
  Alias
```

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting more columns than you are inserting in your table. Your select statement contains 14 columns but your INSERT statement have listed only 13 columns. So, SQL engine is not able to map the last column in your SELECT statement.